# How can we extend a composable outside its parent composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am struggling to build the below view.

[image: Blockquote]

I have added a box and then given some padding and the basic layout works fine. but I am struggling to get the green line beyond the scope of inner composable. Similarly the dotted line in the end.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
    val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
    Canvas(Modifier.width(1.dp).fillMaxHeight()) {

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, -size.height),
            end = Offset(0f, size.height),
            pathEffect = pathEffect
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Green line is not visible outside the inner composable is because you have given a padding on the outer composable.
Instead of giving padding use the fillMaxHeight and fillMaWidth modifiers for changing the height and width of inner composable w.r.t outer composable.

[image: visual representation of my masterpiece]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
            .height(300.dp)
            .width(200.dp)
    ){
       Box(
           modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxHeight(0.9f)
               .fillMaxWidth(0.99f)
               .align(Alignment.Center)
               .border(2.dp, Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(15.dp))
       )
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(start = 20.dp)
        ){
            Divider(
                color = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(5.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`offset` can make the child overflow the parent.

The premise is their parent not use `Modifier.clipToBounds()`